# how to calculate the area of a rectangle interstices by a circle

Tags: geometry, area

I need to make two calculations:
1. determine to arc that is needed between the two intersection points of a rectangle. Knowns: Size of the rectangle, location of the intersection points; No part of the arc can enter region A to C, and D to B.

2. I want to calculate the area of a rectangle intersected by a arc (see above).

Attached is an illustration of the area I need to calculate.
[image]

Comment: This doesn't look like a programming question. I don't understand what you're asking at all, though.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to solve this problem with the information given. Three points are required to define a circle, yet you only have to points.

You can construct multiple *possible* circles given two points on a rectangle. For example:

[image: Two points do not make a circle]

Have you been given any extra information about the circle (e.g. **radius**, diameter, circumference, center, etc.)?